# Longtable border disappears and wrapping text in it

Tags: longtable, wrap

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Conversion}\vline    &\multirow{2}{*}{Function}  &\multirow{2}{*}{Examples}\\\cline{1-2}
        \textbf{From}   &\textbf{To}    &   &\\\hline\endhead
    \end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

I need a table heading like the following image. But the left border of `Conversion` is disappeared by my coding. Additionally if I need to wrap the contents of table cells, what do I need to do?
[image]

Comment: If you just use `c` you remove the rule. Try `\multicolumn{2}{|c}{Conversion}` instead.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz isn't the preamble of ```longtable``` sufficient to place a border for ```multicol```?

Comment: No. If you use `c`, that will be interpreted as asking for (pseudocode) `no_rule centred no_rule`.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz how do I wrap texts there?

Comment: Have  a look at the tabularray package. It makes merging cells etc. much easier